# Unable to add/see local server in Server Manager

Tags: active-directory

I would like to add a local server to my Server Manager (I'm on Windows 10). My purpose is to have this local server simply for my local software development.

But whenever I go to Server Manager and click Manage->Add Servers the Add Servers dialog shows the below message:

[image]

Any advice on how I can simply just add a local server/have my local server show up?

AFAIK I have enabled Active Directories. I don't think I have created any domains. I'm just doing this for local development of software with a SQL Server and C#.

[image]

Comment: You have to have a Domain Controller installed either on your Machine or in the Network. Enabling AD-Services doesn't mean you have installed and configured a DC which is mandatory for AD services to work (how would your PC know what Domain to search for then?).

Answer (score 1):

If you select the DNS tab, you can add the server by DNS name or by IP address.  You need to make sure you have the appropriate ports for remote management open on the server you are adding and once added, you may see a red x on the server icon or a an "Access Denied" because it will try to connect to it with the credentials you are logged into the workstation with.  You can right-click on the server object and select "Manage As" from the pop-out menu to enter credentials that are in the local SAM of the server.